# Error while installing react JS wiht the message: Unknown command: "create-react-app"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, cmd, npx

I got this trouble when I try to install react JS with my npm.

this is the massage:

```
Unknown command: "create-react-app"
To see a list of supported npm commands, run:
  npm help
```

What should I do?

Comment: Did you try `npx create-react-app` ? It will ask you to install `create-react-app`

Comment: I was try, but I just got that massage

Answer (score 0):

Use `npx create-react-app appname`

React docs
https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

`create-react-app` is obsolete you must be using old docs or tutorials
GoodLuck

Answer (score 0):

When you create react app use npx not npm.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```